# Where to put the page-initialize javascript when using pjax?

Tags: javascript, pjax

Most of the times, I put some javascript code in `$(document).ready` to do some initialization stuffs on the page, like event binding, etc.

But now I would like to use `pjax` https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax for some of my pages.

With pjax, because there's only part of the page gets refreshed, `$(document).ready` will not get called again.

I could manually trigger the initializing script on event `pjax:end`, but I also want to know if there's a better solution for that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best bet is probably just to do what you said and hook your page specific init code up to the "pjax:end" event. That way it'll essentially be doing the same job that it did before and run against whatever html has been loaded in to the DOM.

Answer (score 57):

You can easily link all your existing code to both the document.ready and pjax:success events, like so:

Before:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // page load stuff
});
```

After:

```
$(document).on('ready pjax:success', function() {
    // will fire on initial page load, and subsequent PJAX page loads
});
```

Comment: What can I do if the initialization code is different for each page?

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks so much for this.

Comment: @Adrian Macneil - What can I do if the initialization code is different for each page?

Comment: @Vonfry  I use location page `window.location.pathname`

Answer (score 4):

I have came up with this neat solution. You first start by creating a namespace for your binders in the global scope:

```
// Binder for PJAX init functions

$.fn.bindPJAX = {}; // Create namespace

function bindPJAX(functionName) {
  // Check function existence, then call it
  return $().bindPJAX[functionName] && $().bindPJAX[functionName]();
}
```

Then bind a callback to PJAX clicks:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if ($.support.pjax) {
    $('a[data-pjax]').on('click', function(event) {

      var container = '#main';
      var emptyRoute = 'feed'; // The function that will be called on domain's root

      // Store current href without domain
      var link = event.currentTarget.href.replace(/^.*\/\/[^\/]+\//, '');
      var target = link === "" ? emptyRoute : link;

      // Bind href-specific asynchronous initialization
      $(document).on('ready pjax:success', container, function() {
        bindPJAX(target); // Call initializers
        $(document).off('ready pjax:success', container); // Unbind initialization
      });

      // PJAX-load the new content
      $.pjax.click(event, {container: $(container)});

    })
  }
});
```

When this is set up, you can proceed to extend the `$.fn.bindPJAX` object to add functions that will match your route name. For example, this, in the global scope, will be called when accessing `http://www.yourdomain.com/admin` via PJAX:

```
$.extend($.fn.bindPJAX, {
  admin: function(){
    // Initialization script for /admin route
  }
});
```

You should also consider a viable DRY fallback when PJAX fails or isn't supported, like launching the correct init function on first pageload by checking `window.location` in javascript, or maybe hardcoding it in your application's views.