# Can't run scripts after PJAX load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, pjax

I'm using PJAX for a project. 
I have a container called #icerikAlani to load its content with PJAX.
Here is the basic layout:

```
<div class="container" id="icerikAlani" data-pjax-container>   
    <!-- NIVO SLIDER --> 
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider"> SLIDER CONTENT HERE... </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- SCROLLING LOGOS --> 
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="logoParade"> SCROLLING LOGOS HERE... </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This container has two other script tags in it which are for Nivo Slider and Smooth Div Scroller plugins. 
The problem is, when I navigate to a page and return to homepage, script tags stop working.

I tried to solve this problem by using pjax:end statement but I couldn't make it work, then I tried pjax:success as below bu still no luck. (as I read here: [Where to put the page-initialize javascript when using pjax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696119/where-to-put-the-page-initialize-javascript-when-using-pjax/10613657#10613657))

Is there a way for using these scripts without reloading the page?

This is the script about PJAX and Smooth Div Scroller script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).pjax('a','[data-pjax-container]', { fragment: "#icerikAlani" } );
    //THIS IS HOW I ACTIVATE PJAX

    $(document).on('pjax:beforeSend', function() {
    $('#icerikAlani').fadeOut(50);
    }); 
    //WORKS...

    $(document).on('pjax:end', function() {
    $('#icerikAlani').fadeIn(400);
    });
    //WORKS...

    $(document).on('ready pjax:success', function() {
      $("#logoParade").smoothDivScroll({ 
                     autoScrollingMode: "always", 
                     autoScrollingDirection: "endlessLoopRight", 
                     autoScrollingStep: 1, 
                     autoScrollingInterval: 25 
             });
   //FAILS...
});
</script>
```

You can check the full code [here](http://otuzel.com/SUB/selamoto/index.php)

Because I'm not experienced about javascript, this problem stands like a wall against me before finishing the project. Hope to find something works both with the slider and the scroller.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly your script causes an error.
Try Firefox and Firebug and see if you find something...